# How to apply each color to each square

Tags: python

I am working in a project to detect each rubiks cube color from a face, each color form the face is represented by a square, and the color square should be the inside square color, however, it doesn't. All the squares take the color from the top left square.

This is the code:

```
    while True:
    aframe, frame = cam.read()
    img = frame.copy()
    img1 = img[100:200, 100:200]
    img2 = img[100:200, 210:310]
    img3 = img[100:200, 320:420]
    img4 = img[205:305, 100:200]
    img5 = img[205:305, 210:310]
    img6 = img[205:305, 320:420]
    img7 = img[320:420, 100:200]
    img8 = img[320:420, 210:310]
    img9 = img[320:420, 320:420]

    subcares = [img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7, img8, img9]
    def color():
        for p in subcares:
            r, g, b = cv2.split(p)
            r_avg = cv2.mean(r)[0]
            g_avg = cv2.mean(g)[0]
            b_avg = cv2.mean(b)[0]
            rr_avg = int(r_avg)
            gg_avg = int(g_avg)
            bb_avg = int(b_avg)
            return rr_avg, gg_avg, bb_avg
    for j in values:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, j, (j[0] + 100, j[1] + 100), color(), 4)
    cv2.imshow('Cam', frame)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please check you code indentation, and provide a [MRE].

Answer (score 0):

For filling drawn rectangles. Put "-1"

```
cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (w, h), (255, 255, 255), -1)
```

Also, it's missing the meaning of variable `values`, please check it.

Comment: values = [(100, 100), (100, 210), (100, 320), (210, 100), (210, 210), (210, 320), (320, 100), (320, 210),
              (320, 320)]

Comment: I mean, I want each square with a different color depending of what is the camaera detecting in that area, for example, the first square red, the second blue... However, they take all the color of the 1rst